# Angular components html not wrapped by the selector

Tags: html, angular

I have a component called bid-input, and it displays an `input` field. In some place in the application it works as intended first picture being the display in browser and second the element selected from the developer tools.:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that when I use the same component at another place in the app the `bid-input` code is as if it is not wrapping the `html` it presents:
[image]
[image]

The input field displayed here is actually code residing in `bid-input` 
and it is functioning correctly, but the problem is that some css styles are not applied because of this.

I can not share the code behind this, but It would be great if anyone has seen this and knows why / how it occurred.

Comment: if you cant share code and help us to reproduce, you only have a slight chance if finding someone able to help you. Could you at least add the component template where you use the bid-input component?

Comment: @PierreMallet I know that without code my chances do not look so good. I can not post code since it is company property, but even if I could the structure behind is pretty complicated and gets through many components to finally display what is displayed. So I am just counting on the slim chance that someone has encountered a similar problem and can share what was causing it, instead of "fixing" my problem.

Comment: I don't think the template of your wrapping component will display a lot of sensitives information =) neither the template of the bid-input component. Best luck to you!